# DocuSign SMS Authentication : Mask phone number and show only last 4 digits

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign API to send envelopes with SMS authentication enabled. When I open the envelope for signing, the SMS Authentication window displays the phone number.

Is there a setting in DocuSign to mask the phone number and show only last 4 digits of it on SMS Authentication window?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the method described in the DocuSign API Guide referenced here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/phone-auth/

If so, you should be able to create your own workflow.
Using the Admin UI you can go to "Identity Verification" setting under "SIGNING AND SENDING".
Then you can "Add Configuration" which will be your own workflow that you can configure with some settings (including masking part of the phone number).

After saving, you should have access to the workflowId you can use in the API call when sending the envelope.

Comment: I am using the DocuSign C# SDK to enable SMS Auth from the code rather than creating an identity verification workflow as can be seen below:

Signers = new List<Signer>
{
   new()
   {
      IdCheckConfigurationName = "SMS Auth $",
      SmsAuthentication = new RecipientSMSAuthentication()
      {
        SenderProvidedNumbers = new List<string>()
        {
           Model.CountryCode + Model.MobileNumber
        }
      }
   }
}

Can we enable the masking at envelope or template level rather than creating identity verification workflow?

Comment: With this method you won't be able to enable the masking of the phoneNumber. Going through identity verification workflow is the best way and you can set it up when creating the envelope/template

Comment: Thank you Cyril for the reply and sharing your thoughts. I have outlined the approach below which we are going to take for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Masking of phone number for our approach mentioned above can be enabled/disabled at account level by raising a support ticket to Docusign or by segregating the specific settings in a subaccount.

We are going to get a subaccount created in DocuSign so that required settings can be configured as per our needs without affecting common account settings of our organization.